# Nuitka - convert Python to C: Cannot locate suitable C Compiler

Tags: python-3.x, mingw-w64, nuitka

I am having issues with Nuitka; trying to convert python to c language, I get the following error;

> Error, cannot locate suitable C compiler. You have the following
>   options:
>
> a) If a suitable Visual Studio version is installed, it will not be
>   located    automatically, unless you install pywin32 for the Python
>   installation    below "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Python36_86".
>
> b) To make it find Visual Studio without registry execute from Start
>   Menu    the 'Visual Studio Command Prompt' or "vcvarsall.bat". That
>   will add    Visual Studio to the "PATH". And it then will be detected.
>
> c) Install MinGW64 to "C:\MinGW64" or "\MinGW", where then it is
>   automatically    detected or add it to PATH before executing Nuitka.
>   But be sure to pick the    proper variant (32/64 bits, your Python
>   arch is 'x86'), or else cryptic errors    will be shown.
>
> Normal MinGW will not work! MinGW64 does not mean 64 bits, just better
>   Windows compatibility. Cygwin based gcc will not work. MSYS2 based gcc
>   will not work. clang-cl will only work if MSVC already worked.

I did the following;

- pip install pywin32 and it has already been satisfied (installed under site packages)
- installed MinGW64 from win-builds program on their website (tried both 64 and 32 bit versions)

  - checking version via cmd: `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version` I get the following error;

Error:

> The code execution cannot proceed because libiconv.dll was not found.
>   Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

After adding libiconv.dll to file location manually; I get the following error;

Error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).

- I also tried running as admin and get same issue.

I am obviously not doing something right, can anyone help me get MinGW64 installed correctly or fix the issue with other options?